# How would one go about Re-sorting ListView Items By Date

Tags: android, android-listview

How would one go about resorting these listview items by date so it displays from newest to oldest. I would figure using a loop in the GetView but i'm unsure about the logic to get it done.

Each one of those list items have a cell containing all the information about the listitem, such as a date, title and icon.

Would appreciate any help on the issue.

[image]

Comment: If you have a custom object you could implement your own comporator or comparable interface and then match the data fields to their required order

Comment: @kabuto178 Maybe you can add your two cents on this, but would that still work if these items are dynamic and are updated via database query.

Comment: Yes it should, as long as you update your listview, and run the comparison again it should order the items in a List<object> as you indicated it to be.

Comment: why didnt you just use ORDER BY with your sql command ?

Comment: @LinhNguyen I did use ORDER BY, however there are multiple SQL queries being fed into the listview. Unless I found out a way to integrate all of the queries together then it would work.

Comment: well, I think you should use @ kabuto178's solution or write your own sort method :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this at the database level by using ORDER BY as several people had mentioned in the comments. Only reason before I couldnt do this is because they were all separate queries, but I combined them all together using UNION.